# Where to store information using php - Best Practice

Tags: php, session

first of all sorry if my english will be a little bad!

I'm a newbie of PHP programming and i've some questions:

I'm developing a website using PHP. In this site i have a login: more of one php page is accessible only to logged user, and in all of this pages i check if the user is logged using $_SESSION["user"] variable, that, if it is instantied, contains the username. Is repeating this control each page a bad practice? What are alternatives?

Then, an user could be an admin or a tester and i get this information doing a query when i need (more of one time for the same session of the user). Should i use another $_SESSION variable to store these informations? and check this variable where i need?
(In this moment i do a query to get (again) this information).

Is to use a SESSION variable secure?

I ask because i've same code in more pages, and this doesn't seem a good practice.

Regards, Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, depending on the structure of your code, you could create a php file which will work as a controller and will have some basic configuration all of your other pages will inherit.

$_SESSION is not a bad idea as long as you use it correctly. Since the user is logged in from the very start, you can keep in session the important information, like their username or their role permission in order to be able to call them immediately without making connections to the database constantly.

But you have to be careful on the security of this issue too, as there is always the risk of someone affecting this data from the browser. So the session should have an expiration time limit and the data should be encrypted.

These configurations could be set up from your main php class, and as a result inherit the methods of this class methods on every other php page you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With the first approach you suggested, should i create a php file with a class from which other files intherit? Would be great to see an example of this approach.

With the second approach you suggested, how can i encrypt data into $_SESSION ? Is there a php function to do this?

Comment: My approach is one, you could create a main php file (basically an interface) and into there create your sessions. The content of the sessions could be encrypted for better. Check this link on how to set up and interface. [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) Basically it is a php class which inside will have anything you want (the setup of the sessions for example). Later with the "implements" you can pass it to your other class.

Comment: As for the encryption it is not necessary, as php does some settings on advance for you.You can also read this response from another answer I just found which explains the main issue of security. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161147/is-there-any-security-benefit-to-encrypting-session-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161147/is-there-any-security-benefit-to-encrypting-session-variables). I just suggested to set an extra encyption on your data before passing it to session (ex. MD5), but it will not change a lot the operation, so I guess you can leave it for now.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but if i can use directly session_start(); $_SESSION['username'] why should i use an interface ? have i not directly the value using session variables? Inheritance does not provide me information I could not reach otherwise or am i wrong?

Comment: Implementing the interface on your pages, you wouldn't have to check specifically on every page if the user is logged in or if they are admin or not. The method of your interface will be implemented automatically and will make the appropriate checks of the sessions. So you will avoid repeating the same checks on your code.

Comment: Ok, this answer is very clear! I understand, thank you!